# AmCharts 4 tooltip negtive and positive color of single LineSeries

Tags: tooltip, amcharts

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-line-chart/

In above have a LineSeries Chart with positive and negative values with different line colors but tooltip have only negative value color.

Can this possible to have positive line have different color of tooltip and negtive have another tooltip color?

Comment: As you can see in the chart when line goes to negative value line color is 'purple' and tooltip background is 'purple' it is fine but when it is goes to positive values line becomes 'blue' but tooltip is still 'purple' now tooltip should be blue color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible.

Firstly, to [adjust the background color of a tooltip](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/overriding-series-tooltip-fill-color/), you'll need to kill its default behavior of grabbing color information from the calling object (in this case it gets the `fill` from the series). That's done via:

```js
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
```

Then to adjust the background:

```js
series.tooltip.background.fill = // color here
```

To switch its background color based on the value it's showing, one way we can do that is use an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for the series' `tooltipText`, because when that triggers we know the tooltip is being shown and/or changing. In there we can detect the current `dataItem` being sourced, check the value, and adjust the tooltip's background `fill` accordingly.

Sample code:

```js
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.tooltip.background.fill = "blue";
series.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(tooltipText) {
  if (series.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.visits < 0) {
    series.tooltip.background.fill = "red";
  } else {
    series.tooltip.background.fill = "blue";
  }
  return tooltipText;
});
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/913514e19a189c8779e07ffcae861ce3